# Android methods in on create

Tags: java, android

I'm new to programming and got myself stuck.I'm writing in java building an android app in eclipse.

I've been testing an application and all my functionality has been inside my onCreateView in my fragment. I've finally got it all working but its now a bit messy. I was going to move certain parts out into their own methods.

However when I call this method in the onCreateView it now crashes.

The current working app looks like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_tab, container, false);


    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    db.createUser(new User("Sam"));
    db.createUser(new User("Gabriel"));
    username = db.getUser(IDnumber);
    displayName= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewTest);
    displayName.setText(username.getName());

    return rootView;
    }
```

When I amend it to this:

```
public void displayData(){

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    db.createUser(new User("Sam"));
    db.createUser(new User("Gabriel"));
    username = db.getUser(IDnumber);displayName= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TextViewTest);
    displayName.setText(username.getName());
}
```

and call it in onCreateView, it crashes.

I'm pretty sure its to do with the rootView which I changed to getActivity() in the second attempt but I'm not sure what else I should change it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare your view in class outside of oncreateview method, initialize it in oncreateview method so you can use it

```
 View rootView
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_tab, container, false);


     displayData();



    return rootView;
    }


public void displayData(){

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    db.createUser(new User("Emma","Team", "School"));
    db.createUser(new User("Sarah","team", "School"));
    username = db.getUserFromTable(userIDTest);
    displayName= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewTest);
    displayName.setText(username.getUserName());
}
```

alternate way just initialize all your controls in oncreateview view and use it anywhere you want in that class

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your views in `onCreate`, and put the rest in your `displayData` method

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_tab, container, false);

    displayName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewTest);
    displayData();

    return rootView;
}

public void displayData(){
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    db.createUser(new User("Emma","Team", "School"));
    db.createUser(new User("Sarah","team", "School"));
    username = db.getUserFromTable(userIDTest);
    displayName.setText(username.getUserName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getActivity()` just give it the context by using `ActivityName.this`
. Please post your error from logcat.

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow this process create method `init_var(rootView);` then add this only `context = getActivity();` hope solve your problem